# Kubernetes container connection to RDS instance in separate VPC

Tags: docker, amazon-rds, kubernetes, amazon-vpc

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in Amazon EC2 inside its own VPC, and I'm trying to get Dockerized services to connect to an RDS database (which is in a different VPC). I've figured out the peering and routing table entries so I can do this from the minion machines:

```
ubuntu@minion1:~$ psql -h <rds-instance-name>
Password:
```

So that's all working. The problem is that when I try to make that connection from inside a Kubernetes-managed container, I get a timeout:

```
ubuntu@pod-1234:~$ psql -h <rds-instance-name>
…
```

To get the minion to connect, I configured a peering connection, set up the routing tables from the Kubernetes VPC so that `10.0.0.0/16` (the CIDR for the RDS VPC) maps to the peering connection, and updated the RDS instance's security group to allow traffic to port 5432 from the address range `172.20.0.0/16` (the CIDR for the Kubernetes VPC).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of Kelsey Hightower, I solved the problem. It turns out it was a Docker routing issue. I've written up the details in a [blog post](http://ben.straub.cc/2015/08/19/kubernetes-aws-vpc-peering/), but the bottom line is to alter the minions' routing table like so:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d <RDS-IP-ADDRESS>/32 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: trying to see if this is my issue, or if I have another one. is this still an issue 5 years later in k8s? Looks like the code was refactored and the container_bridge.go that contained that isn't there anymore. I also listed my ip info and didn't see the !10.0.0.0/8 rule anywhere. I'm guessing they updated this part of the code unless others have recently ran into the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify the source/destination checks as well?

Since your instance will be sending and receiving traffic for IPs other than the one assigned by your subnet, you'll need to disable source/destination checks.

See the image:
https://coreos.com/assets/images/media/aws-src-dst-check.png

Comment: Source/dest. check is "false" for both my minions. :P