# How can I get kubernetes resources to succesfully connect to an RDS instance in another vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vpc

**Background:** I have a kubernetes cluster set up in one AWS account that needs to access data in an RDS MySQL instance in a different account and I can't seem to get the settings correct to allow traffic to flow.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Setup a peering connection between the two VPCs. They are in the same region, us-east-1.
- Created Route table entries in each account to point traffic on the corresponding subnet to the peering connection.
- Created a security group in the RDS VPC to allow traffic from the kubernetes subnets to access MySql.
- Made sure DNS Resolution is enabled on both VPC's.

**Kubernetes VPC details (Requester)**

This contains 3 EC2's (looks like each has its own subnet) that house my kubernetes cluster. I used EKS to set this up.

The route table rules I set up have the 3 subnets associated, and point the RDS VPC CIDR block at the peering connection.

**RDS VPC details (Accepter)**

This VPC contains the mysql RDS instance, as well as some other resources. The RDS instance has quite a few VPC security groups assigned to it for access from our office IP's etc. It has Public Accessibility set to true.

I repeated the route table setup (in reverse) and pointed back to the K8s VPC subnet / peering connection.

**Testing**

To test the connection, I've tried 2 different ways. The application that needs to access mysql is written in node, so I just wrote a test connector and example query and it times out.

I also tried netcat from a terminal in the pod running in the kubernetes cluster.

```
nc -v {{myclustername}}.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
```

Which also times out. It seems to be trying to hit the correct mysql instance IP though so I'm not sure if that means my routing rules are working right from the k8s vpc side.

```
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: ec2-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com != ip-{{IP OF MY MYSQL}}.ec2.internal
```

I'm not sure what steps to take next. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

*Side Note: I've read thru this [Kubernetes container connection to RDS instance in separate VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972109/kubernetes-container-connection-to-rds-instance-in-separate-vpc)
I think I understand what's going on there. My CIDR blocks do not conflict with the default K8s ips (10.0.*.*.) so my problem seems to be different.*

Comment: Couple of things to check: does the RDS DNS name resolve to a public IP (is the DB connection traversing the Internet and not the peering connection)? Have you checked network ACLs?

Comment: The RDS DNS resolves to the private IP of the instance in the subnet I would expect, so I think at least that routing table is working correctly and that means I'm using the peering connection? The ACL's I'm less familiar with. Both VPC's seem to have rules that allow all traffic in the network ACL section.
110   ALL Traffic  ALL ALL  0.0.0.0/0  ALLOW

Comment: So did you check if it really resolves to a private IP? Also have you tried to access the DB from a regular EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed it resolves to a private IP. I haven't tried connecting from a regular EC2, that's a good thought. Could be something to do with kubernetes. I'll set one up and try it. Thanks.

Comment: Also check this out, might be related since you have a peering connection: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/external-snat.html

Comment: Good tip, Ill check it out, thanks.

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, it turns out the security group I was applying the rules to to allow inbound traffic to the RDS instance was associated to the vpc but not the rds instance itself (at least I think thats what the problem was) When I put the rule in a different security group, everything worked.

Comment: In the RDS Security Group that allows access from K8s VPC: can you reference another security group that belongs to K8s VPC (a different account in your case)? I just got my peering connection to work, but the problem is - I don't know what I did.. The last change I made was to add routes to the public subnets' route tables. Which I don't know why I needed... Anyhow, this works now.

Comment: Can you add your own answer to this question and mark it as "correct"? This list of things you had to do to make it work. BTW, the question itself is very well put together and was IMMENSELY helpful to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I just ran into this problem as well.

It turns out I was editing the wrong AWS routing table! When I ran `kops` to create my cluster, it created a new VPC with its own routing table but also another routing table! I needed to add the peer connection route to the cluster's routing table instead of the VPC's Main routing table.

[image: Routing tables]